# Synchronising emails subscribers with mobile connect Contacts data

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I am the admin of an ET environment.  I have several data extensions with information related to email susbscribers. The relationship is 1:N.

I also have Mobile connect in place and I do not know how to synchronise both worlds. I can import all my subscribers to mobile connect as contacts and create some automations to keep them updated but If I want to execute a segmented SMS send with information included in Data extensions I have no way of doing it? At least I do not know how to do it.

I do not know if someone has been in the same situation or if there is any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You have really only one option is you cannot send directly to a DE in MC.  You can only import it.  (Though, you can use AMPscript to do DE look ups in MC messages, but I don't think that's what you're trying to do here).

You need to go to Automation Studio, then:

1. Run an Import Mobile Contacts Activity from Automation Studio.  Map DE column to Contact Attribute 1:1.
2. Run a Refresh mobile filtered list activity to refresh your .... Filtered List!

All segmenting needs to be done ahead of time, before the import happens.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Didnt work for me. Pushing data from Lead Object to Mobile connect using automation seems impossible :(